# How to redefine a varioref macro?

Tags: macros, varioref

I want the final line of this example's output

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{varioref}

\begin{document}
\label{text1start}\blindtext[5]\label{text1stop}
\label{text2start}\blindtext[2]\label{text2stop}
\blindtext[7]

See \vpagerefrange{text1start}{text1stop} and \vpagerefrange{text2start}{text2stop}
\end{document}
```

to look as though I had typed

```
See pp.\ 1--2 and p.\ 2
```

instead of

```
See on pages 1--2 and on page 2
```

So far as I can tell, I can do this by redefining `\reftextpagerange` (and possibly `\reftextfaraway`); but unfortunately the documentation seems to assume the reader is already familiar with the syntax to do this, and I'm not. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

You can look in the source, the english default definitions are

```
\def\reftextfaraway#1{on page~\pageref{#1}}%

\def\reftextpagerange#1#2{on pages~\pageref{#1}--\pageref{#2}}%
```

So you could use similar definitions or using normal latex redefinition syntax:

```
\renewcommand\reftextfaraway[1]{on page foo~\pageref{#1}}%

\renewcommand\reftextpagerange[2]{on pages~\pageref{#1} wibble  hmmm \pageref{#2}}%
```